# Can't retrieve data from firebase database to show inside my textbox

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to get the data from the firebase cloud database, but the data didn't show out.

[This is the code I try to retrieve data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FceRe.png)

```
private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?){
    if(currentUser!=null){
        fstore.collection("users")
            .document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task->
                task.result!!.get("name") == name.text.toString();
                task.result!!.get("email") == email.text.toString();

                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Haha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

[Calling UpdateUI() form activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdx2e.png)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var name: TextView
lateinit var email: TextView

private lateinit var fstore: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    name = findViewById(R.id.name)
    email = findViewById(R.id.email)

    auth   = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    updateUI(auth.currentUser)
}
```

firebase cloud database:

[image]

android simulator after I tried:

[image]

Comment: Please include your code with your question, rather than posting an image of the code.

Comment: do you get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document id assigning is wrong

```
.document(doucumentID) //Not user ID
//Here your document id is 
//JXoTcqxIVENTSF2..... 
//As I can see your firestore image
```

and you are assigning data in a wrong way to `TextView`

```
name.text = "value you want to assign"
```

So edit your code like this

```
private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?){
    if(currentUser!=null){
        fstore.collection("users")
            .document("JXoTcqxIVENTSF2..")
            //can not see full id in image so I use '....'
            //replace it with full id from firestore
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task->

                name.text = task.result!!.get("name").toString()
                email.text = task.result!!.get("email").toString()

                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Haha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```